# Link to comments in the election

Tags: feature-request, comments, election

I just tried to link some comment from the election page only to find out there is no link on the timestamp.

Is this by design? If so: can this be reconsidered. Sometimes I want to link to comments in chat which is not easy to do now.

To make my question a bit less dupe. The comments once linked by doing heavy manual labor (looking up the id in the DOM) also don't onebox in chat.

Comment: Also, clicking the link button on the post actually opens the link, rather than the fancy copy-paste box like we all expect. Sad pandas are sad!

Comment: Crap :( As always I see [a dupe once I've posted my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/comments-on-election-page-dont-have-a-permalink?rq=1). I have searched and I have glanced the dupe list when entering my title. Really... :)

Comment: And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts

Comment: Yesyesyes. Was going to post my own feature request for this. Comment permalinking is a [somewhat new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/), but there's no place where it makes more sense than the elections page. There's _tons_ of comments there -- the feature is basically overloaded to be used as a forum thread.

Comment: @Oded - [The status is completed now!](http://stackoverflow.com/election/4#comment-21213329)

Comment: @Oded the status is uncompleted. We can't get a permalink for comments on the recent ELL's election. (Or wait, was this just for [so] elections?)

Comment: @Oded it also doesn't work on the recent [Anime elections](http://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)

Answer (score 6):

Not yet thoroughly tested. I confirm that it supports the case of loading more comment, and it should also support posting/deleting comment.

I have made some updates since my first revision to fix some bugs.

**This is currently Revision 3**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Timestamp in Election comment
// @namespace      nhahtdh
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/election*
// @grant          metadata
// @author         nhahtdh

function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

with_jquery(function ($) {
    function addCommentLink(ref) {
        $('.comment', ref).each(function () {
            $('.comment-date > .relativetime-clean', this).wrapAll($('<a href="' + '#' + this.id + '"></a>'));
        });
    }

    addCommentLink(document);

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
        if (/\/comments/.test(settings.url)) {
            addCommentLink(document);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a URL that will point to a comment.

All you need is to take a look at the id of the actual comment -

`http://stackoverflow.com/election/4?#comment-21205321`
`-------------------------------------------^`

It's not too comfortable, and a little hacky... but it works never-the-less!

Comment: I know I can look it up in the DOM (that's the part about not be easy). I should have added that in my question. Sorry that I suck at this :(

Comment: I smell a userscript brewing ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa - Nothing feels better than finding [someone else has already done your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135599/172936) ;)

Comment: Why are you referring to me as pee. That's very offensive! Especially bad when you are running for mod! Flagged! ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa - sorry for that.. I'm used to using the minimum 3 character @ replies...

Comment: Also it seems that Manishearth's script doesn't work any more...

Comment: That's ok. I forgive you :-) Would be nice if this would be "fixed" though at some point imho (the functionality I mean although a userscript could be a temporary solution).

Comment: @Lix It works, but only on the visible comments. Doesn't work on comments that show up after you click "add / show n more comments".

Answer (score 2):

Put your hands in the air like you just don't care *(for such crass abstractions as jQuery)*

*Edit: slight improvement to expando link callback to prevent multiple calls and wait until all additional comments have been loaded*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Election comment linkifier
// @description Linkify comment timestamps in SO moderator election
// @version 1.0
// @author DaveRandom
// @namespace https://github.com/DaveRandom
// @match http://stackoverflow.com/election/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

  function addLinksToUnprocessedPosts() {
    var i, l, linkSpan, linkText, anchorElement,
        comments = document.querySelectorAll('tr[id^=comment-]:not(.linkmaker-processed)');

    pending = false;

    for (i = 0, l = comments.length; i < l; i++) {
      linkSpan = comments[i].querySelector('span.comment-date span');
      linkText = linkSpan.firstChild;
      linkSpan.removeChild(linkText);

      anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
      anchorElement.href = '#' + comments[i].id;
      anchorElement.appendChild(linkText);

      linkSpan.appendChild(anchorElement);

      comments[i].className += ' linkmaker-processed';
    }
  }
  addLinksToUnprocessedPosts();

  var i, l, pending = false,
      expandoLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.comments-link');
  for (i = 0, l = expandoLinks.length; i < l; i++) {
    expandoLinks[i].parentNode.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
      if (e.srcElement.nodeType === 1 && e.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr' && !pending) {
        pending = true;
        setTimeout(addLinksToUnprocessedPosts, 0);
      }
    });
  }

}());
```

Tested in a *real* browser (Google Chrome), but I suppose if you must you may sully my fine craftsmanship by using it in *that other one*...

Comment: Good guy Dave strikes again!

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` event is deprecated, at least according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference)

Comment: @nhahtdh Indeed it is, and for very good reasons. However the main problem is with bubbling - not too much of a problem because the node(s) I attached it to have very few child nodes and they don't really change apart from when you click the link. The alternative (mutation observers) is, however, a lot more of a pita to work with. I agreed it's not an ideal mechanism but the other option - without resorting to jQuery - was to poll the DOM for completion which is even more horrible (IMO). Side note: the way in which the SE code deals with adding the extra posts to the DOM is very inefficient.

Comment: @DavidX.Random: +1 for a great comment. I don't code web-related stuffs much, so this is great insight.

Comment: @nhahtdh In a couple of years (hopefully) `MutationObserver` will be the way to do things like this but at the moment it is only supported in Chrome and Firefox, and in Chrome it uses a non-standard name (`Webkit` prefix). Mutation events are very inefficient on the DOM (especially in Firefox) which is why they have been deprecated but for real-world applications where cross browser support is required, i.e. not little overlays like this, unfortunately you are stuck with them at the moment. I started work on an observer abstraction with fallback to events a while ago, but it doesn't work yet.