# I cannot view "more comments" on the election pages

Tags: bug, comments, election

Today, I commented on one of the moderator nominations. Since then, I received a few inbox messages on that comment, stating <kbd>[4 comments <sup>N mins ago</sup> H2CO3's Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?noredirect=1#post-21687077)</kbd>. This probably means my comment got answers referencing me, but I cannot view them. When I click the link, I only get to the nomination itself - [the comments do not yet have any permalinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169015/183280). However, there is also no <kbd>add / show N more comments</kbd> button like on normal posts with many comments - I can only see the top-rated comments without a possibility to expand them.

I now noticed that I can view the comments on which the inbox notified me under the `responses` tab in my profile.

Comment: [status-completed-as-of-the-next-build](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1815042#1815042)

Comment: @Tim: Ah, good to know :-)

Comment: @TimStone Now we're going to see a [meta-tag:feature-request]: close questions as dupes of chat messages. ;)

Comment: @Tim When _is_ the next build? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ben said sometime this morning, but that if it seemed to be taking too long he'd kick one off manually himself. Looks like Meta's already had a build today, but not SO.

Comment: @TimStone: "this morning" in what timezone?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This seems to have been deployed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Ben's chat message](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1815042#1815042), a fix has been deployed that enables the "show more comments" link, so all of the previously hidden comments should now be accessible on the nomination post.

Comment: Although maybe the number of automatically displayed comments should be reduced now, since some of those threads are fairly lengthy even before expanding...