# Side-by-side markdown diffs no longer render newlines. Is this deliberate?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown, revisions-list, diff

Self-explanatory title, I think.

Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21689452/revisions

[image: Yowzer!]

FYI Firefox 26.0 Win XP SP3.

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-norepro]] Works On My Machine™ (IE 10, Win 8 RT).

Comment: No repro in Chrome 32 and Firefox 27. Looks like your browser is misbehaving, check your extensions/userscripts/etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Repro in IE8 too. There's more to it than some extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with a Ctrl+F5 (in both FF26 and IE8, the two browsers I happened to have to hand, and in both of which I witnessed the problem).

Shoddy dependency cache management combined with an adjusted stylesheet?

This still implies the bug would affect other people.