# Why can't I obtain links to comments on the moderator page?

Tags: bug, comments, election, permalink

Is it deliberate that I can't click on the timestamp of a comment on the election page, to grab a link? <strike>I could earlier tonight!</strike> The feature is useful for sharing comments in chat.

*FF26 WinXP SP3*

Comment: What happens in Vegas stays in Vegas.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220337/election-comments-have-no-permalink-link

Comment: @RobertHarvey: All of SO is Vegas. Jokes aside, if _you_ weren't joking, I think the message that election activity should be forcibly kept on election-related pages is not the best message of openness to send out to your constituents!

Comment: Just  look and a y intervención o comentaría

Comment: @user4855086: What?